# In Xcode's Interface Builder, isn't outlet the same as properties, and action the same as event handler?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, action, iboutlet

It seems that using Xcode's Interface Builder, when we `Ctrl`-drag the control to the header file, what we create as outlet is very similar to a webpage's element's properties (attributes), and what we create as action is very similar to event handlers.  Is that true?

I also wonder why we need to `Ctrl`-drag the control to the header file, under `@interface`, instead of just right click on it and choose either "Add outlet" or "Add action".  Why to we have to drag it to an exact place in the header file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, we don't **need** to drag it with **Ctrl**, this is just for ease of using.We can also link our outlets in code.

And, yes, it is really similar to properties. You even can declare it as properties in your `@interface`

```
@property (strong)IBOutlet UITextField *loginField;
```

Here's a good talk on this subject https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/pdx-cocoaheads-talk/ujqrcCZc-Z8

Comment: you mean if we don't use `Ctrl`-drag, we can just add the code?  Couldn't we have right click as well?  Or can it be drag to other header files, so that's why we need to drag and drop to a particular file?

Comment: We drag to particular file,because we want to bind it with particular file.Updated the answer with a Cocoa Heads talk on this question.